# Tigera Calico cause coredns timeout

Tags: kubeadm, calico

I have problem, when i install tigera-calico from helm

> https://docs.tigera.io/calico/charts:tigera-operator

When i launch

> kubectl -n kube-system rollout restart Deployment coredns;

i got this error:

```
kubectl run -it --rm busybox --image busybox /bin/sh
/ # nslookup kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.internal
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
/ # nslookup google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Here is the configuration:

```
---
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta3
kind: ClusterConfiguration
clusterName: kubernetes
controlPlaneEndpoint: main
kubernetesVersion: 1.29.0
networking:
  dnsDomain: cluster.internal
  podSubnet: 10.128.0.0/9
  serviceSubnet: 172.16.0.0/12
controllerManager:
  extraArgs:
    node-cidr-mask-size: '9'
---
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: crd.projectcalico.org/v1
  kind: IPPool
  metadata:
    annotations:
      projectcalico.org/metadata: '{"uid":"43b9bc45-27ef-4319-a143-187057e6ce2c"}'
    generation: 1
    name: default-ipv4-ippool
    resourceVersion: "2334"
    uid: d074f1ff-0896-48bc-97d6-e414c70aeac1
  spec:
    allowedUses:
    - Workload
    - Tunnel
    blockSize: 26
    cidr: 10.128.0.0/9
    ipipMode: Always
    natOutgoing: true
    nodeSelector: all()
    vxlanMode: Never
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
---
```

Anyone have an idea for resolve this?
Thank, Have a good day.

Comment: Your testing may be incorrect. `nslookup` generally queries the name servers that are configured in the system, for Linux and friends that means : configured in `/etc/resolv.conf` - Often  a system running a name server is not configured to use the name server it itself is running as the name server entry in /etc/resolv.conf  and for testing you explicitly query the IP-address of the server you're testing as a command line option in your `nslookup` or `dig` command.

Comment: These tests are just there to show that no pod deployed on one of the worker nodes can access the name resolution of coredns, therefore even the internal Kubernetes services (ex: kube-dns.kube-system.svc .cluster.internal) cannot be resolved.

Comment: PS: Issues that do not appear when a pod is deployed on the main node, where the coredns pods are initially located.